# Import range into every Nth row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Column of data in one sheet. I want to copy that Column into *another* sheet, but this one has cells that are merged. If I do an import range, or a simple formula like `='Sheet'!A1`, it will only get some of the data, because the formula doesn't work that specifically.

This image shows the issue and goal:

[image: image shows the issue and goal]

Comment: Don't merge cells.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=offset(A$2,(int(row()-2)/4),)
```

copied down from B2.

Comment: THIS WORKED. Incredible. I'll note it works for anyone else who tries this, the 4 in the equation is what you'd change if you had more cells merged, so if it was 10 cells it would be
=offset(A$2,(int(row()-2)/10),)